# Parameter name is changed in bin_params using JinjaSql

Tags: python, sql, jinja2

Imagine this is my query :

```
query = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE id = {{myid}}'''
params = {'myid':3}

j= JinJaSql(param_style='pyformat'}

myquery, bind_params = j.prepare_query(query,params)
```

when I print bind_params I would get

```
{'myid_1':3}
```

why my parameter name was changed to `myid_1` while I named it `myid`. Is there anything wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you care?  Does it cause a problem?

Comment: @TimRoberts Good question. Because when I want to load data I get this error
""" read_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'myid_1' """

Answer (score 0):

According to the readme on the [JinjaSql github page](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/jinjasql), if using the `"pyformat"` or `"named"` param style, the bound parameters returned by `prepare_query` are guaranteed to be unique. I suspect that this is why `myid` gets changed to `myid_1`.

When calling `read_sql` you should make sure to use the `myquery` and `bind_params` *returned* by `prepare_query` and **not** the `query` and `params` used in the `prepare_query` call, i.e.

```
# ...
# your code above
# ...
myquery, bind_params = j.prepare_query(query, params)
result = pd.read_sql(myquery, conn, params=bind_params)
```

Note that the format of your params for `pd.read_sql` depends on the SQL dialect you're using ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas-read-sql)). If you're using postgres for example, dictionary params are the way to go.

Hope this helps!